# Neural Network Training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition

I try to recognize pictures of every digit. I have removed everything else than the digit so that there is almost no noise other than the digit is placed differently on the pictures. I use Neuroph's image recognizing gui and have some questions about training.

It seems that the larger resolution I use for the pictures the worser the training becomes. Why is this? I have 100 pictures in my training set. 10 of each digit. Is that maybe too little? Why is every training no matter what i do just converging to some number usually between 2-3 in total network error.

Here is a picture of one of the trainings
[image]

It doesn't learn much

Comment: What type of learing algorithm You use? What are it's parameters? What's the neural net topology? Is that a backprop? Please, provide more details since they are essential in this type of problem.

Comment: The image you see above uses something called a sigmoid transfer function which is a backprop. The learning parameters was the default. Learning rate 0.5 and momentum 0. The neural network used one hidden layer of 12 neurons which i have found gives the smallest error.

Comment: I eventually succeeded in training this network by changing learning rate to 0.35 and randomize the network when it began converging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The information increase is exponential!**

When you provide images with higher resolution, you end up giving extra information which has to be evaluated.

If your resolution is 10x10px, that would result in 100 pixels per image and you have 10 images per digit, that's *1000 pixels per digit*.

Now if you double the resolution to 20x20px it would result in 400 pixels per image or *4000 pixels per digit*.

In other words: increasing the resolution results in an **exponential** increase for the number of pixels you have to evaluate per each digit.

**Adding more (unnecessary) pixels increases the chance of errors:**

Usually, in machine learning the pictures are stripped down to the bare minimum (both in size and color) in order to provide as little room for error as possible. When you have more pixels, the algorithm may learn something about those pixels that is completely irrelevant to the actual form in the image.

Answer (score 0):

For one, I have to second Lirik's comment that increasing the resolution is not helpful here.

Aside from that, 10 samples of each digit is most likely not enough data for your neural net to train with.  10 samples of a digit might not even be enough training data if you were training a *human* to recognize digits in some wierd language that they don't understand.  See if you get better results by increasing the size of your training data to around 250-300 of each digit.  Exactly how much you will need is hard to say without knowing anything about your particular net.

My guess is that you will see better results with more training data and lower resolution images.